# ArcGIS Full-Text search

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, rest

I've set up Full-Text searching on a table in my SDE database (ms sql backend).  I can perform the full-text commands from SQL queries, but it doesn't seem to work in ArcMap or any rest services.  I full-text supported at all in arcgis server?

ie: if i run this SQL query on my server, it returns all trail names that have trail in it (trail, Trail, Trails, etc)

SELECT * FROM dbo.TRAILS WHERE CONTAINS(Webname, '"trail"');

if i add

CONTAINS(Webname, '"trail"');

to the "WHERE" section in arcmap, querying the same table, it gives me an error, saying full-text indexing is not set on that table.

EDIT: i've got it so it doesn't give me the error anymore, but the CONTAINS(Webname, '"trail"') doesn't search for any iteration of trail in the field, it only returns the exact text i was looking for (webnames with "trail" in it, not "trail", "Trail, "Trails", etc)

and ideas?

Comment: I have figured out how to get it working. The main issue being that it seems the table cannot be registered as versioned.

once i unregistered it as versioned (be sure to commit changes to default) you can now use the "contains(field, statement)" inside the where clause for an esri table or feature.

Comment: did you get this to work via the rest endpoint?